# Convert NSDate to Sql Server Datetime format

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sql-server, web-services

I'm calling a .net web service from iPhone application that takes parameter with dateTime data type. I want to pass the Current date. I wanted to know which date format I need to use.
I would appreciate your help,
Thanks

```
NSDate *now=[NSDate date];
```

Comment: Did you solved it? I am also facing same problem. I want to send current date as parameter from webservice. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone: [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithname:@"UTC"]];
NSString *sqlDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: date]; // date is your NSDate object
```

EDIT: Updated answer to take timezone into account. Obviously you should use the same timezone used on the original date.

Answer (score 3):

The more independent way would be sending time in second instead of any format to your web server,

```
NSDate *now = [NSDate date]; 
NSTimeInterval inSecond = [now timeIntervalSince1970];
```

`inSecond` is type of double , and let your web server to calculate the time from the second you send .

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDATE *date;
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"ddMMyyyy"];
NSString *textDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date]];
[dateFormatter release];
```