# Need to convert NSString to Nsdate

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I need to convert "2013-05-05T00:00:00Z"  this string to NSDate and again NSDate to Nsstring. I have tried with different-differnt format style but didn't get any success.

I have already checked.

[NSDate from NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352487/nsdate-from-nsstring)

[Convert NSDate to Sql Server Datetime format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357504/convert-nsdate-to-sql-server-datetime-format)

Thanks.

```
// for getting string for Advance search  

-(NSDate*) doGetDateFromStringGSearch :(NSString*) dateStr 
{

NSDateFormatter * outputFormatter4 = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc ] init ] autorelease ];

NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[outputFormatter4 setLocale:locale];

//[outputFormatter4 setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:SSS"];
//[outputFormatter4 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZ"];
 [ outputFormatter4 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:Z" ];
 //[ outputFormatter4 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss':00Z'" ];

NSString * inputString2 = dateStr;
NSDate * inputRecivedToDate = [outputFormatter4 dateFromString:inputString2 ];
NSLog(@"doGetDateFromString  %@", inputRecivedToDate);

return [[inputRecivedToDate retain] autorelease];
}
```

Comment: whatever u tried....show the code

Comment: Please check now......

Comment: `[ outputFormatter4 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz"];` would work fine. For more details refer this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17010081/767730)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change you formatter string to :

```
[outputFormatter4 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'"];
```

---

The full code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter=[NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'"];
NSDate *date=[dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2013-05-05T00:00:00Z"];

NSLog(@"%@",date);
```

Comment: Can you check out this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17010081/767730) and comments. As per ISO8601 character `Z` is a shorthand for UTC. If you ignore it, there would be timezone issues as default timezone of dateFormatter would be device specific.

Comment: This format will work. But it totally ignores the timezone. The presence of the character `Z` denotes that the string is in UTC. If you ignore this Z, you need to set the timezone explicitly to the dateFormatter. If it is not done, there would be erroneous output based on localTimeZone of the device.

Comment: For date  "2013-05-05T00:00:00Z" it is giving me  "2013-05-04 18:30:00 +0000", it is not proper date :(

Comment: you are in India, which is +5:30 from gmt, so 1830 + 0530 = 0000.

Comment: Thanks Anoop for quick response.  It is not working in case of "2013-06-04T16:55:00Z". If you let me know why it is not working for this date. it would be Great. Thanks

Comment: @Mangesh This is exactly the issue I was talking about. The dateString is in UTC, with the kind of parsing it is doing now. The date formed is in IST(Indian Standard Time) so there would be a lag of 05:30. You can remove it by setting timeZone UTC to the formatter or use the method that I suggested.

Comment: @Anupdas [df_utc setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"]]; yes it is working for iOS 6. ill check for iOS 5. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Anupdas: thanks  buddy, for adding timezone. this completes my answer, I wish I cud hv given you +1...

Comment: @Anupdas, Thank you very much, it is working properly but on iOS 5 it return null in case of "2013-03-24T08:18:31.469Z" string while it is working for other string like "2013-05-29T00:11:00Z"

Comment: @Mangesh 2013-03-24T08:18:31.469Z needs a dateFormat `yyyy-dd-MM'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz` and 2013-05-29T00:11:00Z needs `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz`. DateFormatter is very sensitive to the format specified, try to make your dateString uniform in either of cases.

Comment: even you can extract seconds and milliseconds then use formatters

Comment: Ahhh but it is working in case of iOS 6 :( and it is dynamic. I am not sure which format will come from server. As a quick work around I can check "." in string and then go for specific format. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have been using the NSDateFormatter with `@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZ"` format for many years, but found out that on few, but only few (maybe less then 1%) of devices it was unsuccessful and was returning nil.

So as a fallback I have been using this library: https://github.com/keithpitt/ISO8601DateFormatter and now I am not seeing any issues with parsing ISO8601 date formats.

The library supports both `dateFromString:` and `stringFromDate:`.